# Logstash can't read file

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I'm using Logstash for the first time. I'm on Windows 10
I try to access a multiline json file from a input/ folder like this :

```
input 
{   
    file 
    {
        codec => multiline
        {
            pattern => '^/{'
            negate => true
            what => previous                
        }
        path => "/input/*.json"
        exclude => "*.gz"
    }
}

filter 
{
    mutate
    {
        replace => [ "message", "%{message}" ]
        gsub => [ 'message','\n','']
    }
    if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/ 
    {
        json { source => message }
    }

}

output
{
    file
    {
        path => "/output/output.json"
    }
}
```

The problem here is when i'm launching logstash instance I get this error :

> WARN  logstash.inputs.file - failed to open
>   /input/sample.json: \input\sample.json

I already replace the LS_GROUP by adm in startup.options and tried to replace "/" with "\", didn't work.
I also "chmod 777" my json file but it change nothing.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Going with `/` should work fine. What if you're trying to have the `path` something like this, escaping with `\\`:

```
path => "\\input\\*.json"
```

Make sure you give the complete path.

Comment: Nothing appened at all. To be sure my path is good, I put a json inside "logstash-5.1.1/input/" and another inside "C:/input/"

Comment: Since it's on windows, perhaps the path should begin with c: ? Like :  `"C:/input/*.json"`

Comment: @baudsp yup that's what I thought Magnus should be having it already. So I assumed the issue would've been with the escape key.

Comment: Yeah, but since it's missing from its conf, I just wanted to be sure that's not the problem.

Comment: To build upon what baudsp and Kulasangar suggested, have you tried `"C:\\input\\*.json"` ?