# Logstash read contain on storage physical file using MySQL + Logstash

Tags: mysql, logstash, logstash-jdbc

**Firstly,** I tried all the questions & answers related to this topic. Additionally and I tried related questions and try to solve them but with no success. So please read my question thoroughly.

**Problem:** I read contain on my storage physical file using mysql+logstash.

**My Simple Question:** logstash read contain on storage physical File?

I have using Angular + asp.net core + Mysql on my Application i have read some contain on my storage physical file using mysql+logstash. so i am read many url like

1. [logstash-not-reading-in-new-entries-from-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571490/logstash-not-reading-in-new-entries-from-mysql)
2. [logstash-cant-read-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102637/logstash-cant-read-file)
3. [stored-procedure-in-elastic-search](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/stored-procedure-in-elastic-search/165882)

Comment: Please, explain in your question what you are tryng to do and what is not working, you linked to different problems without sharing what you tried to do and what is not working.

Comment: are you trying to read from mysql or from a file?